# Get around: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have to deal with a RESTful server which is not under my control. When I try to fetch the ID 1 record from it this is the error I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/api/v1/companies/1.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed 
access.
```

I can `curl` it on the shell:

```
$ curl -I http://www.company.com/api/v1/companies/1
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 11055
Content-Type: application/javascript
Last-Modified: Thu, 18 Jun 2015 07:30:26 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "5e772a598a9d01:0"
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml",CP="CAO DSP LAW CURa ADMa DEVa CUSi OUR LEG UNI"
Date: Fri, 19 Jun 2015 13:06:46 GMT
$
```

I use the following contentSecurityPolicy:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  'default-src': "'none'",
  'script-src': "'self'",
  'font-src': "'self'",
  'connect-src': "'self' http://www.example.com",
  'img-src': "'self'",
  'style-src': "'self'",
  'media-src': "'self'"
}
```

How can I fix this? How can I tell Ember to just use it?

Comment: You can use browser plug-in to get around this.

Comment: Which one would that be?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting `contentSecurityPolicy` allows the browser to actually make the request from `http://localhost:4200` to `http://www.example.com`.

If you didn't have this set, you would be seeing an error like:

> [Report Only] Refused to connect to 'http://www.example.com/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' http://localhost:* ws://localhost:* ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729".

After doing the request, if `http://www.example.com` doesn't contain a particular header that actually allows `http://localhost:4200` to make these requests, the browser throws an error..

For more information take a look at this question: [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

If you're using Ember CLI for development you can proxy all ajax requests to `http://www.example.com/` using:

```
ember server --proxy http://www.example.com/
```

But this doesn't solve your problem when moving to production. You will need some other solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

This may be an old thread, but this answer may help those who refer to this in the future.
Try using the `@CrossOrigin` annotation in the restful method you access. Example:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
```